# Using word vba is it possible to detect the font when a sentence is selected?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Does anyone know how to determine the font size of a sentence using word vba?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=word+font+name+size+vba

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub FontDetails()
    With Selection.Font
        MsgBox .Name & ", " & .Size & " points"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I actually was looking for a way to do, If then else and found a way to do it. I had to declare a paragraph object and then do range and then do font and size. Thank you for the post.